# Assembly Information

Tags: asp.net

Hi I am working in .net project.

I want to display the assembly information on the page.

User will enter the name of .net assembly in a textbox and then need to display information like all the properties, functions with parameters, constructors, destructor and inherited class names.

Please give  some solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is [System.Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Reflection;
```

For loading assembly dynamically,use

```
Assembly asm=Assembly.LoadFile(@"Full path of .dll file");
```

Now to get all types in assembly,use

```
Type []alltypes=asm.GetTypes();
```

For information about methods, constructors,parameters,properties use

```
MethodInfo []GetMethods() ,ConstructorInfo []GetConstructors() ,ParameterInfo []GetParameter() ,PropertyInfo []GetProperty() etc and iterate.
```

And many more method are there,see the MSDN of `System.Reflection`